# Compiling Qt projects in Qt/MsBuild format without Qt VS Tools installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, msbuild, qt-vs-addin

I have many Qt projects in Visual Studio, using the [new Qt/MsBuild format](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/02/16/qt-visual-studio-improving-performance/) provided by the Qt VS Tools. When compiling in my development environment, where I have the Qt VS Tools installed, everything works flawlessly (compiling from IDE and from command line).

We have a computer dedicated to nightly builds, where only the compiler and msbuild are available (no IDE nor Qt VS Tools are installed).

When compiling the projects in such computer we get an error:

> QtMsBuild: could not locate qt.targets, qt.props; project may not build correctly.

Followed by several lines such as

> e:********\Preferences.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_Preferences.h': No such file or directory

(Project contains `Preferences.ui`).

How can I solve such errors when Qt VS Tools are not installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One solution provided by the Tools' creators is to copy `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtMsBuild` into each project directory. But we are talking about hundred of projects. Doing manually, and more on, pushing them as part of the project itself doesn't sound very elegant.

One option would be to add a pre-build step that copies it from a common place into each project (and adding a `**/QtMsBuild` line to each .gitignore file). Again, looks like too much work.

When looking at the .vcxproj file for the Qt project you find this fragment (the reason for the solution provided by creators):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(QtMsBuild)'=='' or !Exists('$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets')">
  <QtMsBuild>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\QtMsBuild</QtMsBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So, the simplest solution (without being able to install the tools), is to copy the `%LOCALAPPDATA\QtMsBuild` directory (from a system with the Tools installed) into the night computer (in any common place, but I decided to keep the location used by the tools) and then setting an environment variable:

```
set QtMsBuild=%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtMsBuild
```

PS: do not add double quotes to the variable (at least I had problems with them, so VS couldn't find the files).

#### Update 9-14-2020

I'm not sure on which version it started, but Qt projects created with (at least) the v2.5.2 Qt VS Tools fails to compile indicating that the Qt version has not been set. To solve so, you can

1. Copy the Registry entries from a computer with tools installed, located at `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Digia\Versions`.
2. If you will rely on a single Qt version (but that may be update globally for all projects), you can skip the Registry and just set the Qt version of all projects to `$(DefaultQtVersion)` (the same used in past project formats) and define an environment variable pointing to the directory of the version: `set DefaultQtVersion=c:\Qt\Qt_5_15_0\Win32`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems in my case setting up `$Env:QtToolsPath="$Env:QT_PATH\bin"` fixed the problem. (It was not finding qmake for some checks). This, I think, is required when using QtMsBuild v3.3

Not sure if this info is 100% correct but may help someone.

For me to use MsBuild with Qt using QtMsBuild (not installing Visual Studio and/or VS plugins), I need to set up:

Example (PowerShell):

```
- $Env:PATH="$Env:MSBUILD_PATH;$Env:PATH"
- $Env:QT_PATH="D:\BuildTools\Qt\5.15.1\msvc2019_64"
- $Env:QtMsBuild="D:\BuildTools\Qt\QtMsBuild303" #303 Against visual studio project version
- $Env:QtToolsPath="$Env:QT_PATH\bin" #Support QtMSBuild , At desktop is done by the plug in
- $Env:PATH="$Env:QtMsBuild;$Env:PATH"
- $Env:PATH="$Env:QT_PATH\bin;$Env:PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit this and got it working.

I followed @cbuchart 's advice; but needed to do a little more/different.

So here is what I did.  I copied `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtMsBuild` to my repo.  I then edited my `.vcxproj` with a text editor.  I adjusted the line that looks like:

```
<QtMsBuild Condition="'$(QtMsBuild)'=='' OR !Exists('$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\QtMsBuild</QtMsBuild>
```

To be:

```
<QtMsBuild Condition="'$(QtMsBuild)'=='' OR !Exists('$(QtMsBuild)\qt.targets')">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\QtMsBuild</QtMsBuild>
```

Depending on the relative location of where your project(s) are to the copied `QtMsBuild` directory you might want to adjust this.  In my case the `.vcxproj` was in a directory one level from the directory that contains the `QtMsBuild` directory I copied.

Next in the `QtMsBuild/Qt.props` file I added the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <DefaultQtVersion>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\Qt5.15.0\msvc2019_64</DefaultQtVersion>
   <QtToolsPath>$(DefaultQtVersion)\bin</QtToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That was added right after the opening `Project` tag in that file.

This was as @cbuchart mentioned something might have changed.  I didn't do the Registry idea; but added those lines instead.  I think it is possible to add them to a different file that gets imported before `Qt.props` if desired.

Now as for what this "Qt5.15.0\msvc2019_64" is; you'll need the tools, includes, libraries from a computer with Qt installed in order to build (also DLLs if your build needs to run the executable (i.e. tests)).  This might be a lot of files so you can reduce it some if you know what you are doing.  It might make sense to have these be put into it's own submodule or something.

After that it should `uic`/`moc` files and ultimately build (and run).

Answer (score 0):

I got too. Maybe you need update your visual studio and then restart your computer ...
problem solved. reason: install 'qt vs tools' latest version but the visual studio
not support of it.

Comment: I think you are answering for a different issue. The question asks how to compile Qt project _without_ the Qt VS Tools installed.