# How to configure Jenkins to build solutions with Qt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, jenkins, msbuild

I'm about to switch from CruiseControl.NET to Jenkins.

My problem with the build process is the error "**QtMsBuild: could not locate qt.targets, qt.props; project may not build correctly**."
I have already tried several solutions but without success. Changing the build methods (*NAnt/MSBuild*) also produces the same error message. 
In Visual Studio under Project Properties (*C/C++ > Additional Include Directories*) I noticed that **QTDIR** is not known although it exists as an environment variable (as an example instead of {QTDIR}\include I only get \include).

I am using:
Qt 5.9.0, MS Visual Studio 2015, Qt Visual Studio Tools (V2.3.2)

In the past I have tried on using an older version of the Visual Studio Tools plugin how the developers recommend. I also checked the paths and set environments variables. Giving Jenkins the path  "*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild*" as parameter does not changed anything.

I do not want to copy the files from "*C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild*" into each build directory, because at ccnet it's working.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, have you checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082148/compiling-qt-projects-in-qt-msbuild-format-without-qt-vs-tools-installed). And if you build the project within VS, it succeeds? After that, use the developer command prompt, what's the result?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. 
The build process in VS is successfull. I added QTDIR and QtMsBuild as properties in Jenkins and extended the NAnt script with a  <setenv> block. This solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to know your issue has been solved and thanks for sharing your solution! You can add it as answer and mark it! Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this solutions works:

1. add **QTDIR** and **QtMsBuild** at the NAnt build process as properties in Jenkins

Example:

```
QtMsBuild=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\QtMsBuild
QTDIR=D:\\Qt 5.9.0\\qtbase
```

2. extend the NAnt script with a `<setenv>` block

Example:

```
<setenv>
      <variable name="qtdir" value="${QTDIR}" />
      <variable name="qtmsbuild" value="${QtMsBuild}" />
</setenv>
```